# dompdf a way to remove the footer on the last page?

Tags: php, dompdf

Using DOMPDF 0.6.0 beta 3, I try to build a pdf with a variable number of text pages followed by a last page that is filled with clients logos. 
I want to have a image in the footer on all the pages except the last one.

I use this for now, and it adds the footer on all the pages including the last one:

```
  $footer = $pdf->open_object();

  $w = $pdf->get_width();
  $h = $pdf->get_height();

  $y = $h - 2 * $text_height - 24;

  $img_w = 590; 
  $img_h = 170; 
  $pdf->image("footer-pdf.png", ($w - $img_w) / 2.0, $y - $img_h, $img_w, $img_h);

  $pdf->close_object();

  $pdf->add_object($footer, "all");
```

add_object() can receive the (all, add, odd, even) parameters but i can't see something that can control the last page.

I tried using the $PAGE_NUM and $PAGE_COUNT to check if they are equal it means i am on the last page and do some stuff there. But both $PAGE_NUM and $PAGE_COUNT return 1 everytime.

Any idea on how to remove the footer on the last page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <script type="text/php">
if ( isset($pdf) ) { 
    $pdf->page_script('
        if ($PAGE_COUNT > 1 && $PAGE_NUM!=$PAGE_COUNT ) {
            $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "normal");
            $size = 9;
            $pageText = "Page " . $PAGE_NUM . " of " . $PAGE_COUNT;
            $y = $pdf->get_height() - 24;
            $x = ($pdf->get_width() /2) - ( Font_Metrics::get_text_width($pageText, $font, $size) / 2);
            $pdf->text($x, $y, $pageText, $font, $size);
        } 
   ');
}   
 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I could swear i didn't stumbled on page_script() method in the documentation :) Anyway, thank you.

Comment: That function hasn't been added to the documentation yet. Since the script is run on every page after dompdf has completed rendering the HTML it's a lot like using objects, but offers more flexible. When the docs are updates for 0.6.0 it will be noted.